# C# Winforms How to override scroll events?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` with `autoscroll` set to `false`, `anchor` to `topleft`. It's parent is a `Panel` with `autoscroll` set to `true`.

The `TableLayoutPanel` is being populated all the time with dynamic controls.

The scrolling itself works very good when there are few controls, just hundreds. However, when I get more and more controls the performance of scrolling downgrades and sometimes it freezes my PC.

Basically when I click on the vertical `Scrollbar` it fires an unlimited amount of `ThumbPosition` messages.

Part of my program

[image: Part of my program]

Using the `Scroll` event on the panel, not the tablelayoutpanel, I can catch some user events like `LargeDecrement`, `ThumbTrack`, `ThumbPosition`, etc but I can't see `EndScroll` being triggered which is the one I want. Or atleast I want to cancel scrolling on `ThumbPosition`.

```
    private void FormaDinámicaGrisG_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Type + "");
        if (e.Type == ScrollEventType.ThumbPosition)
        {
            //I want to prevent scrolling here
        }
        else
        {
            // Here I want to let it scroll.
        }
       
    }
```

I try using the following code to catch messages when user is scrolling but nothing happens.

```
private const int WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115;
private const int WM_HSCROLL = 0x0114;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    if (m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Vertical Scroll");
    }
    if (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("HorzScroll");
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

I believe the problem is that since it has so many dynamic controls, and the events triggers so rapidly in succession it hangs on drawing it.
So any idea to stop scrolling on certain events and let other events scroll?

Comment: The only good advice is to throw this away.  Using TLP to implement a grid control is never not a drastic mistake.  Use a grid control instead.

Comment: Like which one. Using a DataGridView for example? When I was designing this, I saw people using TableLayoutPanel to accomodate multiple controls in a grid....